# How can I trigger a text which will be showed up at the end?

Tags: javascript, html

There will be many other question like the one below. But the problem is I want that every question will create a text. For example if you click "yes" button of first question there will be created a text such as " You clicked yes button of first question.

It's okey thus far but how can I also trigger a text which will be showed up after all questions?

```
"There will be first question."
<form>
    <input type="radio" value="yes" onClick="location.href='question triggered by yes'">
    <input type="radio" value="no" onClick="location.href='question triggered by no'">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to skip `javascript` and simply use the CSS *pseudo-class* `:checked`:

```css
input ~ p {
    display:none;
}

.question1Yes:checked ~ .question1YesRecorded,
.question1No:checked ~ .question1NoRecorded {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<p>1. Your first question - will you answer Yes or No?</p>

<input type="hidden" name="question1" value="question1Unanswered">
<input type="radio" name="question1" class="question1Yes" value="question1Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="question1" class="question1No" value="question1No">No

<p class="question1YesRecorded">You answered <strong>Yes</strong></p>
<p class="question1NoRecorded">You answered <strong>No</strong></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need but here is a function that will create some text for you:

```
function create_text(answer) {
    if(answer === "yes")  return "some text";
    if(answer === "no") return "some different text";
}
```